# Catalog Search index process always fail

Tags: magento2, reindex, opensearch, catalogsearch-fulltext

Catalog Search indexation never end succefully.

I am using Opensearch with elasticsuite. I have 3 Vms

- VM1 : Magento
- VM2 : Mysql
- VM3: Opensearch

Magento : I have Magento with 7 stores and more than 90 000 products

Mysql Configuration :

```
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
key_buffer_size                            |          64.000 MB |
query_cache_size                           |           0.000 MB |
innodb_buffer_pool_size                    |        8192.000 MB |
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size            |           0.000 MB |

innodb_log_buffer_size                     |           8.000 MB |
table_open_cache                           |           0.001 MB |
max_heap_table_size                        |        4096.000 MB |
query_cache_type                           |           0.000 MB |
thread_cache_size                          |           8.000 MB |

+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
BASE MEMORY                                |        8264.000 MB |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
sort_buffer_size                           |           0.250 MB |
read_buffer_size                           |           0.125 MB |
read_rnd_buffer_size                       |           0.250 MB |
join_buffer_size                           |           0.250 MB |
thread_stack                               |           0.188 MB |
binlog_cache_size                          |           0.031 MB |
tmp_table_size                             |        4096.000 MB |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
MEMORY PER CONNECTION                      |        4097.094 MB |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
Max_used_connections                       |                 11 |
max_connections                            |                550 |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
TOTAL (MIN)                                |       53332.031 MB |
TOTAL (MAX)                                |     2261665.562 MB |
+------------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

Opensearch : Jvm options configuration `-Xms4g -Xmx4g`

The command
`bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext` use 100% of the CPU.

When I configure the indexation with 1 process, I get this error message :

```
Catalog Search index process killed
```

With 2 processes:

```
Catalog Search index process error during indexation process: 
Fail in child process
```

Update :

Now when i execute the same command with memory limit in parameter,

```
php -dmemory_limit=15G bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

I got :

Catalog Search index PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16106127360 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-catalog/Helper/AbstractAttribute.php on line 172
PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16106127360 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

Any help please ?

Thanks

Comment: Please post TEXT of OS Command Prompt results for  A) top - entire 1st page and 
B) free so we know how much ram is available on your mysql server.